# Interchange of summation in infinite sum of vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$, and $T\in B(H)$ has matrix representation $[x_{ij}]$ with respect to the given basis.

If $\sum_{j=1}^\infty h_je_j\in H$, is the following interchange of summation valid?

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_jx_{ij}e_i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty h_jx_{ij}e_i$$

I was trying to relate it to Fubini, but I can't get any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid, and both expressions are equal to $T^*h$. First note that for each $j$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle e_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle e_i,T^*e_j\rangle e_i=T^*e_j$$
Therefore,

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle e_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle T^*e_j=T^*\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle e_j=T^*h$$
and for the other expression, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle\cdot\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle) e_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\langle Te_i,h\rangle e_i=T^*h$$

Comment: I’ll get back to this when I’m in front of my computer, but something minor to note is I’m using an inner product whose linear in the first component. So I believe there shouldn’t be adjoints on the Ts.

Comment: Was able to parse it out now, and indeed it is correct with the remark that I am using the inner product to be linear in the first component so I have mine without the adjoints. Thanks!